# What is the meaning of “commonwealth” in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Here is an excerpt from the book called *I’m right and You’re an Idiot*.

> You don’t choose what you believe; you believe what you believe because you are furnished with the kinds of evidence that impel a certain kind of cognition. People have what Kahan called a ***“commonwealth” of sensibilities, values and dilemmas*** that exert control over them and can cause them to misunderstand things.

In this context, what is the meaning of the word “commonwealth”?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mening must be this one.

From *SOED*

> **commonwealth** **3** *fig.* Any aggregate of persons or things united by some common factor.

In the case of the present sentence the things are abstract concepts ( sensibilities, values, dilemmas, …). The common factor is the characteristic common to all these mental elements of being put to work  on the decision process.